# Get result in from YouTube channel in nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, youtube, youtube-api

I am using youtube-node npm to find out all the video list. The documentation is on the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-node.

But I want that my search only show result of a specific channel i.e if I search **hello**, then it only give result of **AdeleVEVO** YouTube channel.
I cant find suitable documentation for that. I don't want to use oauth credentials, I only want to use youtube-node npm.

Comment: 1st of all try that with native API of youtube to see if that's even possible or not. After that you can use some node package to replicate that in an app

Answer (score 1):

In package doc you have a sample search, make sure you include in the params parameter an object with the values you want, in your case see in [youtube api doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#optional-parameters) that you need to specify the channelId. Try this way:

```
var YouTube = require('youtube-node');

var youTube = new YouTube();

youTube.setKey('AIzaSyB1OOSpTREs85WUMvIgJvLTZKye4BVsoFU');

youTube.search('World War z Trailer', 2, {channelId: <string value of the channelId>}, function(error, result) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
  }
})
```

;

Answer (score 0):

If you are the owner of the channel, you can use the **forMine** parameter of the YouTube API for this. Setting this parameter will limit the search to the authorized user's videos. Below is a sample from [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Do not use the `youtube-node` module for this, specifically because--in my experience at least--the `addParam()` function does not reliably add parameters to the request (e.g., in my code I called `youtube_node.addParam('safeSearch', 'strict');`, but restricted videos would still be returned in the results.)

Instead, use the YouTube Data API directly as shown in [this quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs).

```
  // Sample nodejs code for search.list

  function searchListMine(auth, requestData) {
    var service = google.youtube('v3');
    var parameters = removeEmptyParameters(requestData['params']);
    parameters['auth'] = auth;
    service.search.list(parameters, function(err, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(response);
    });
  }

  //See full code sample for authorize() function code.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), {'params': {'maxResults': '25',
                   'forMine': 'true',
                   'part': 'snippet',
                   'q': 'fun',
                   'type': 'video'}}, searchListMine);
```